# How can i get all index of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

How can i get all index of array,

```js
[  
   {  
      "name":"aloha",
      "age":"18"
   },
   {  
      "name":"hello word"
   },
   {  
      "name":"John Doe",
      "age":"28"
   }
]
```

Output should be like [0,1,2]

Comment: Please refer this AlexC https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Consider trying something before asking question.

Comment: every array index start form zero and end at the number one less than the length of array. what you want to ask, ask properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest way would be to (see [this post](http://davidarvelo.com/blog/2014/12/array-number-ranges-in-javascript-es6/)):

```js
let a = [{1: 'x'}, {1: 'y'}, {1: 'z'}]
let b = Array.from(a.keys())
console.log(b)
```

and the naive solution is by calling `map((_, i) => i))` on your array:

```js
let a = [{1: 'x'}, {1: 'y'}, {1: 'z'}]
let b = a.map((_, i) => i)
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.keys also to check keys index of any object.

```js
let a = [
        {
        'name' : "aloha",
        "age": "18"
        },
        {
        "name": "hello word"
        },
        {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age" : "28"
    }]
    
console.log(Object.keys(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach loop, like this example:

```
//The array you want to get all the indexes from
const array = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}];
//All indexes array
const indexArray = [];

array.forEach((el, i) => {
    indexArray.push(i);
});
```